# How can I add OFB mode to 3DES with RSA?

Tags: java

When I run my *code*, decryption appears like symbols and it's not similar to plaintext(It's not the correct result in cryptography). How can I solve this problem ?

**See Picture Below**

```
    import java.security.Key;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    
    public class Hybrid_Implementation {
    
    //RSA_Encryption Algorithm Required Variables
    private static final BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    private BigInteger privatekey;
    private BigInteger publickey;
    private BigInteger modulus;
    
    //3DES_Encryption Algorithm Required Variables
    private byte[] DES_Key;
    private SecretKeyFactory keyfactory;
    private DESedeKeySpec spec;
    private Key deskey;
    private int DES_Key_Length;
    private byte[] data;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private String CipherText;
    private byte [] CIPHERText;
    
    Hybrid_Implementation() throws InvalidKeyException, 
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException
    {
        DES_Key_Generator();
        RSA_Key_Generator(999);
    }
    
    //3DES Encryption-Decryption Algorithm with 2 differnt keys
    private String DES_Encryption(String plaintext) throws InvalidKeyException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        data = plaintext.getBytes();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deskey);
        CIPHERText = cipher.doFinal(data);
        StringBuilder hexCiphertext = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<CIPHERText.length; i++)
        {
            int v = CIPHERText[i] & 0xff;
            v+=0x100;
            String temp = Integer.toString(v,16);
            hexCiphertext.append(temp).substring(1);
        }
        return hexCiphertext.toString();
    }
    
    private String DES_Decryption(byte [] key, byte [] encrypted_text) throws 
    InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException
    {
       spec = new DESedeKeySpec(key);
       deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);
        byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(encrypted_text);
        StringBuilder decrypttext= new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++)
            decrypttext.append((char) plaintext[i]);
        String decrypted_plaintext = decrypttext.toString();
        return decrypted_plaintext;
    }
    
    private void DES_Key_Generator() throws InvalidKeyException, 
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String key = rnd.toString();
    
        DES_Key = key.getBytes();
        spec = new DESedeKeySpec(DES_Key);
        keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede");
        deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("desede");
    }
    
    
    //RSA Encryption-Decryption Algorithm
    //RSA Encryption of 3DES Key
    private BigInteger RSA_Encryption(BigInteger des_Key )  
    {
         BigInteger encrypted_DES_Key = des_Key.modPow(publickey, modulus);
         return encrypted_DES_Key;
    }
     //RSA Decryption of 3DES Key
    private BigInteger RSA_Decryption(BigInteger encrypted_DES_Key)
    {
        BigInteger des_Key = encrypted_DES_Key.modPow(privatekey, modulus);
        return des_Key;
    }
    //RSA Public - Private Key Generation
    private void RSA_Key_Generator(int number)     
    {
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.probablePrime(number/2,random);
        BigInteger q = BigInteger.probablePrime(number/2, random);
        BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(one)).multiply(q.subtract(one));
    
        modulus = p.multiply(q);
        publickey = new BigInteger("65537");
        privatekey = publickey.modInverse(phi);
    }
    
    private String encryption(String plaintext) throws InvalidKeyException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        String cipher_text = DES_Encryption(plaintext);
        BigInteger RSA_DESKey = RSA_Encryption(new BigInteger(DES_Key));
        String temp_key = RSA_DESKey.toString();
        DES_Key_Length = temp_key.length();
      
        CipherText = new StringBuilder().append(temp_key).append(cipher_text).toString();
        return CipherText;
    }
    
    private String decryption(String encrypted_text) throws InvalidKeyException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
    {
        StringBuilder encryptedkey = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < DES_Key_Length; i++)
            encryptedkey.append (encrypted_text.charAt(i));
        StringBuilder cipheredtext = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = DES_Key_Length ; j< encrypted_text.length() ; j++)
            cipheredtext.append (encrypted_text.charAt(j));
        BigInteger DES_Encrypted_Key = new BigInteger(encryptedkey.toString());
        BigInteger DES_KEY = RSA_Decryption(DES_Encrypted_Key);
        byte[] decrypt_key = DES_KEY.toByteArray();
        String plaintext = DES_Decryption(decrypt_key,cipheredtext.toString().getBytes());
           return plaintext;
    }
    
    /**
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws InvalidKeyException
     * @throws IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws BadPaddingException
     * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeyException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        String plaintext;
        Hybrid_Implementation hi = new Hybrid_Implementation ();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Text = ");
        plaintext = sc.nextLine();
        String encrypted_text = hi.encryption(plaintext);
        String decrypted_text = hi.decryption(encrypted_text);
        System.out.println("Plain Text Entered = "+plaintext);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text = "+encrypted_text);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text = "+decrypted_text);
        }
    
    }
```

How can I solve this problem **(output attached)**, and how can I add **OFB** mode of operation to **3DES** with **RSA** code above ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50lMV.png)

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not see any output. Kindly edit your post and add a complete sample dataset (plaintext, ciphertext, key(s)). Kindly focus on one question [cut off the OFB-mode question], thanks. A general advise: you should debug the intermediate results on encryption and decryption side (e.g. is the DES-key equal before RSA encryption to "after RSA decryption")

Comment: Well edited.Please re-check.Regards,

Comment: The code has several bugs: Hex encoding does not work, hex decoding is missing and no `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` is set during decryption. I would recommend to analyze the used functionalities one by one (hex encoding, 3DES encryption, RSA encryption etc.) and also compare them with solutions from the Internet, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/9014097 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/9014097. RSA key generation and encryption are supported by Java. There is no need for a custom implementation (your variant does not use padding and is insecure).

Comment: Regarding the mode s. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)